# How can I add a smooth animation to my View when shifting it up/down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I'm using the following code to shift my UIView up/down when the keyboard is initiated in order to keep it from covering my textfields. The code works great, but the movement isn't as seamless as I'd like it to be. Would love some help re: the code I'd need to add in order to make the view movement smooth rather than choppy. Thanks in advance :)

**Update:** I changed KeyboardDidShow to KeyboardWillShow, and doing so causes the following crash error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController
>   keyboardDidShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145e0f530

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    return YES;
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    // Assign new frame to your view
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,375,667)]; //here taken -20 for example i.e. your view will be scrolled to -20. change its value according to your requirement.

}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,375,667)];
}
```

Comment: Fix the `@selector` you pass for the "will show" notification to `@selector(keyboardWillShow:)`.

Comment: And you should not be hardcoding the frame sizes. Extract the keyboard size info from the notification.

Comment: @rmaddy Noted & fixed the crash :) How can I stop the delay that occurs though? My keyboard comes up first, and my view animates up after?

Comment: You need to use `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, not `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your frame changes in [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,375,667)];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your code inside animation blocks:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification{

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                  animations:^{

                                     [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-110,375,667)];

                                  } completion:nil];

}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification{

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0
                                       delay:0.0
                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                                  animations:^{

                                     [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,375,667)];

                                  } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Except you want to animate the view with the "keyboard will show" notification, not the "keyboard did show" notification.

Comment: And the duration should be pulled from the notification, not hardcoded.

Comment: @rmaddy Keyboard Will Show causes a crash. Keyboard Did Show works, but the keyboard comes up first, and the view animation is delayed...

Comment: @Brittany Update your question with details about the crash.